# In R, compare string variable of two dataframes to create new flag variable indicating match in both dataframes, using a for-loop?

Tags: r, dataframe, for-loop, compare

I have two dataframes which I would like to compare. One of them contains a complete list of sentences as a string variable as well as manually assigned codes of 0 and 1 (i.e. `data.1`). The second dataframe contains a subset of the sentences of the first dataframe and is reduced to those sentences that were matched by a dictionary.

This is, in essence, what these two datasets look like:

```
data.1 = data.frame(texts = c("This is a sentence", "This is another sentence", "This is not a sentence", "Yet another sentence"),
                    code = c(1,1,0,1))

data.2 = data.frame(texts = c("This is not a sentence", "This is a sentence"),
                    code = c(1,1))
```

I would like to merge the results of the `data.2` into `data.1` and ideally create a new `code_2` variable there that indicates whether a sentence was matched by the dictionary. This would yield something like this:

```
> data.1
                     texts code code_2
1       This is a sentence    1      1
2 This is another sentence    1      0
3   This is not a sentence    0      1
4     Yet another sentence    1      0
```

To make this slightly more difficult, and as you can see above, the sentences in `data.2` are not just a subset of `data.1` but they may also be in a different order (e.g. "This is not a sentence" is in the third row of the first dataframe but in the first row of the second dataframe).

I was thinking that looping through all of the texts of `data.1` would do the trick, but I'm not sure how to implement this.

```
for (i in 1:nrow(data.1)) {
  # For each i in data.1...
  # compare sentence to ALL sentences in data.2...
  # create a new variable called "code_2"...
  # assign a 1 if a sentence occurs in both dataframes...
  # and a 0 otherwise (i.e. if that sentence only occurs in `data.1` but not in `data.2`).
}
```

**Note:** My question is similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59560914/compare-two-dataframes-in-r), where the string variable "Letter" corresponds to my "texts", yet the problem is somewhat different, since the matching of sentences itself is the basis for the creation of a new flag variable in my case (which is not the case in said other question).

Comment: Why is 3rd row `code` a zero? Because it already is a zero in the original `data.1`?

Comment: That's not really important, it's just a pre-assigned code and that code is assigned manually in `data.1` and based on a dictionary approach in `data.2`. Imagine you'd like to code if there are any fruits mentioned in a set of sentences. If that's not the case, e.g. if there's a sentence like "I like books!", that sentence would get assigned a 0. And obviously there are some differences between the manually coded texts and the dictionary results.

Comment: To clarify, "code" in `data.1` is different from "code" in `data.2`. Both try to measure the same thing but there are divergent opinions between the human coder (`data.1`) and the dictionary (`data.2`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the following `match` based solution does what the question asks for.

```
i <- match(data.2$texts, data.1$texts)
i <- sort(i)
data.1$code_2 <- 0L
data.1$code_2[i] <- data.2$code[seq_along(i)]

data.1
#                     texts code code_2
#1       This is a sentence    1      1
#2 This is another sentence    1      0
#3   This is not a sentence    0      1
#4     Yet another sentence    1      0
```

Answer (score 2):

can you just join the dataframes?

NOTE: Added replace_na to substitue with 0

```
data.1 = data.frame(texts = c("This is a sentence", "This is another sentence", "This is not a sentence", "Yet another sentence"),
                    code = c(1,1,0,1))

data.2 = data.frame(texts = c("This is not a sentence", "This is a sentence"),
                    code = c(1,1))

data.1 %>% dplyr::left_join(data.2, by = 'texts')  %>%
  dplyr::mutate(code.y = tidyr::replace_na(code.y, 0))
```

Comment: Wow, thanks! I made this way too complicated... Of course, that works! Is there a way to automatically get `0` instead of `NA` as values for `code.y` if there is no match?

Comment: That is, `1,0,1,0` instead of `1,NA,1,NA`.

Comment: @FabianHabersack Yes, the vector must be created beforehand.